# Open facebook specific post form android app

Tags: android, facebook

i am trying to open facebook specific post from android app in facebook app currently i am doing this but the facebook app is not showing my post its giving error

```
public static String FACEBOOK_URL = "https://www.facebook.com/" + PAGE_ID
                + "/posts/" + post.getId;


public String getFacebookPageURL(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        int versionCode = packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).versionCode;
        if (versionCode >= 3002850) { //newer versions of fb app
            return "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + FACEBOOK_URL;
        } else { //older versions of fb app
            return "fb://post/" + post.getId();;
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return FACEBOOK_URL; //normal web url
    }
}
```

is there some kind of facebook sdk to open posts and pages ?

Answer (score -1):

please checkout this link, which is of Facebook API

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

also you can get particulate post from Facebook

see this link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/post